# How to Deep Clone an Kotlin object with property delegates

Tags: kotlin

I am searching for the Lib which can make a deep clone of a Kotlin object with delegates.

```kotlin
class Model {
    val p1: String by Delegate()
    inner class InnerModel {
        val p2: String by Delegate()
    } val m = InnerModel()
}
```

And I want to use it in a such way:

```kotlin
val m1 = Model()
val m2 = m1.clone()

m1.m.p2 = "asd"

assertNotEquals(m1.m.p2, m2.m.p2)
```

Apache's BeanUtils can't handle it.

Comment: How cloning is supposed to work in the case of delegates if they could have their arbitrary logic which is not at all "copiable"? Simple example: lazy properties. How to copy them to a new object?. I think what you ask is impossible. Not only for technical reasons, but even conceptually.

Comment: I believe it is doable via Kotlin's reflection. And I have already implemented it as well.  I just want to compare my solution with some others.

Comment: Well, on second thought, copying the internal state of the delegate seems like a pretty universal solution, no matter what is the internal logic of the delegate. Is this what you do right now?

Comment: Here is my solution: 
`val v = p.getter.call(this)!!.clone()
 p.setter.call(cloned, v)`
Where `p` is a KMutableProperty<*>, cloned is a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils 
import kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty 
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

fun<T: Any> clone(obj: T): T {
    val res = obj.newInstance()
    res.copyProps(obj)
    return res 
}

fun Any.copyProps(from: Any) {
    this::class.memberProperties
        .filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty<*>>()
        .forEach {
            val v = it.getter.call(from)!!
            val cls = v.javaClass
            if(cls.name.endsWith("String") || ClassUtils.isPrimitiveOrWrapper(cls)) {
                it.setter.call(this, v)
            } else {
                it.getter.call(this)!!.copyProps(v)
            }
        }
  }
```